# Is it possible to control a DJI drone in two control modes simultaniously?

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to set a waypoint mission to my drone from an app, while maintaining a constant altitude above the ground.
To do this, I plan on setting a waypoint mission while controlling the altitude with the `MobileRemoteController` and "manually" setting the throttle stick based on the values from the ultra-sonic height sensor.

My question is if it is possible, to "manually" change the throttle axis of the drone while flying a waypoint mission.

Answer (score 0):

No,  you cannot be operating multiple control modes at the same time.

To achieve what you want you would need to use virtual joystick and perform all flight controls yourself.